# what does m[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine()) do?

Tags: java

```
public class TestMatrica {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     double matrica[][] = new double[2][2];

     inputElements(matrica);
     printElements(matrica);
 }

 private static void inputElements(double m[][])
 {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
     for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++)
         {
             System.out.println("Unesite element na poziciji [" + i + ", " + j + "]: ");

             m[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine()); ///////////            }
     }
     in.close();
```

ok so my question is what does  (in.nextLine()); in  m[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine()); do

Comment: You should form a habit of reading the [Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). Look for the classes `Double` and `Scanner` (which is the type of your `in`), and find the methods there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the value of m[i][j] will be given by whatever the user types in. Assuming the person types in an integer, it will parse a 2 to a 2.0. If he types a string the program is sure to crash.

Comment: but what does (in.nextLine()); do ?

Answer (score 0):

It just first converts input given as string to double value and then puts that cell of the 2D matrix or two dimensional array. Basically this is a procedure to fill up a two dimensional array or 2D matrix with user provided input numbers.